# How to automate activation of a HIKVISION DS-2CD2512F-IS?

Tags: linux, automation, cryptography

I've got a HIKVISION DS-2CD2512F-IS, and I'm trying to automate the activation step from a Linux box, and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to reverse-engineer how the web interface does it. Setting up everything else is easy - it's just a matter of uploading a bunch of XML files to the URL with the username and password embedded in the URL - but the initial activation step to set the password is driving me nutty. Sure, I can do it easily through the web interface, or through the HIKVISION software ... but if the camera works out, they'll need to be activated 30 at a time by a hundred different guys every year all around the country, and a typo in a password means that camera won't play. Plus, of course, the contractors who'd be doing this are not exactly 100% reliable on reading or following instructions (no exaggeration, it's pretty common for a contractor to say "Nobody told me I'd need to bring that" when it's on the work order in three different spots, in bold), so I can't be sure they'd bring a laptop with the appropriate software to be able to do it anyway. So for reliability and labor cost reasons, I'd like to automate everything involved. The only sticking point for me so far is the activation step on the camera.

At all of these locations, I'm going to ship a linux box under my control (it's a cloned image). I can put a bash script on the master for that (as well as any command-line programs I like), and assign a button on the machine to run it, no problems, and I'm confident in automating everything except the activation at this point.

Now, their customer service team sent me an activation guide (Which you can see here: http://docdro.id/ntP7v8w), but whoever wrote it apparently didn't have English as their first language. I've used WireShark to listen in on the exchange between my browser and the camera, and it's definitely using the referenced API to do the actual activation. I can't seem to make it work, though. My test script so far ... I can't seem to get it to render well here, sadly. Going through the camera's javascript (painful, as someone ran a minimizer on it, so there aren't any comments and all the variables are single letters) suggests that I need to:

1)    Generate my RSA key.
2)    Change my key out of base 64 into binary.
3)    Convert the binary key into a base 16 key.
4)    Re-encode that base 16 key into base 64.
5)    Transmit the key to the camera (wrapped in XML).
6)    Change the return out of base 64 (after unwrapping the XML).
7)    Convert that extracted information into binary, treating it as a base 16 human-readable integer for the conversion.
8)    Convert that binary information into the base64 that openssl takes.
9)    Decrypt the camera's response with my key from 1.
10)    Use said random string as an AES key (which... will very likely involve steps 7 and 8 again) to encrypt my password with openssl.
11)    Extract the binary data from that result by undoing the base64 transition.
12)    Convert that binary data into an ascii-encoded base-16 integer
13)    Convert that ascii-encoded base-16 integer into base64
14)    transmit that to the camera (wrapped in XML)

... and I'm hitting a bit of a brick wall in figuring out how to make that happen in Linux. Any help?

As a side note, it seems the API pages referenced in the documentation remain active post-activation... not an issue for my planned implementation, as they'll all be on a physically isolated network, but not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a web site, then just automate the web site. It's rather easy with [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium), which likely has a binding for your favorite language. You can use different browsers including a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or any desktop browser headlessly through xvfb.

Comment: That got it... just needed PhantomJS itself, plus a bunch of research. The javascript on the camera throws an error when the camera's javascript references a variable that PhantomJS doesn't support (specifically throws "TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$.cookie("page",null)')"), but that comes after it activates the camera, which is sufficient for my purposes.  Thank you.  I'll see about editing the question with the full script I ended up using.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Updated.  Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 10):

Hikvision Activation Guide with ISAPI interface.

1. First of all, check that cam supports activation and activation haven't been done already. For that just read this page with GET request without autorization:
   CAM_IP/SDK/activateStatus
   If camera supports activation, it responds with XML:

> ```
> <ActivateStatus xmlns="http://www.std-cgi.com/ver10/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
> <Activated>true</Activated>
> </ActivateStatus>
> ```

and in the tag "Activated" there's "true" value if cam've been already activated or "false" - if not.
If cam doesn't support activation, it respond with something like this:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html><head><title>Document Error: Unauthorized</title></head>
> <body><h2>Access Error: 401 -- Unauthorized</h2>
> <p>Authentication Error: Access Denied! Authorization required.</p>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

2. Generate RSA keys with length 1024 bits and e=65537. "n" part of public key convert to hex-string like a (every byte is converted to 2 characters):
   b0d89eb193490db47f1f0d419f4962e610d96ed71e592b2bc017e8089ea45d990970af604018bbf450c488d5c08f8954b6d0d88a6388039c93d4bd4df36cf25a349bc1cc91f6484821a789ad7cea524429f817a9f14ccdb2fd46566d6f6dbcea60d152a40cd649d660dac0b8e269f024787bd3d7d15dcd4656ca2f4cc583cb2f

Then this string encode with base 64. Result string put into the tag "key" of the next XML:

> ```
> <PublicKey>
> <key>publickey</key>
> </PublicKey>
> ```

and send with POST-request to CAM_IP/ISAPI/Security/challenge

3. After that we receive an answer like this:

   > ```
   > <Challenge version=“2.0” xmlns=“http://www.isapi.org/ver20/XMLSchema”>
   > <key>MDcyYzhlODc5NTRlOGJkODY1YWE0NDVmYzQ2YWU5MGQyNWZiNmI5ZDk1ZWRkYzRkOTRl MmRmYmNjZjhmNThmMzQ4NTA3ZTYyODI5YzkyZjZlNjNlMDY2ZjUzM2E1MWY2MGJhYjllNDk3NW NjNjNhZGM0MTcxZjhkNjk1M2MyN2YxOTNkZTc1NDdiZmU2ZGNkNTQ2ZmVhN2U0NTAwZjJkOTlk MTlkZjJkM2YyODM0ODQ2MjQyMjE5ZGE3MjY5NDI0YTMyZjY3NjNhM2JjOTEwZmU1ZTg2YTgzMzB lZjE3NDQ1ZWNjMzA4MzEzYzNkMjYwOGQzZjFjM2ZlMDEwNGFkYg==</key> </Challenge>
   > ```

String from tag "key" decode with base64, it's hex-string like this:
072c8e87954e8bd865aa445fc46ae90d25fb6b9d95eddc4d94e2dfbccf8f58f348507e62829c92f6e63e066f533a51f60bab9e4975cc63adc4171f8d6953c27f193de7547bfe6dcd546fea7e4500f2d99d19df2d3f2834846242219da7269424a32f6763a3bc910fe5e86a8330ef17445ecc308313c3d2608d3f1c3fe0104adb

Convert it to byte array (every pair of chars to one byte, the same way converting used in all steps, in this example it should start with 0x07, 0x2c, 0x8e, ...). Decript it with private RSA key (generated at step 2) and take last 32 bytes of decrypted result. It should be another hex-string.

4. Result string from step 3 convert to byte array. This array will be used as AES-key. Encrypt with this key the first 16 bytes of the result string of step 3.
5. Then you need to choose new password for the cam. If it's shorter than 16 symbols you need to fill password string with characters \0 to length 16. After that encrypt it with the same AES-key.
6. Concatinate arrays of bytes from steps 4 and 5 and convert it into hex-string (every byte is converted to 2 characters). Encode result string with base64.
7. Result base64 string of step 6 put into tag "password" in the next XML:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <ActivateInfo>
> <password>pass</password>
> </ActivateInfo>
> ```

and send with PUT-request to:
CAM_IP/ISAPI/System/activate

The answer should be:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <ResponseStatus version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema">
> <requestURL>/ISAPI/System/activate</requestURL>
> <statusCode>1</statusCode>
> <statusString>OK</statusString>
> <subStatusCode>ok</subStatusCode>
> </ResponseStatus>
> ```

There's python script for batch-configure Hikvision Cams with activation:
https://github.com/qb60/Hikvision-batch-configure

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @qb60 What do you mean by that " Last 32 bytes of it uncript with private RSA key (generated at step 2) " ?? I don't know how "unscript bytes with RSA key".

Comment: @BartekGładys, sorry, I meant "decrypt". Just look "ACTIVATION" section in my script on github if you understand python, it's quite clear.

Comment: @qb60 Unfortunately I can't use python in my implementation. I'm using node.js and libraries differ. BTW Have you got any problem with taking modulus from the public key(step 2)? To make it work, I had to remove the first 2 signs "00". Otherwise, I've got "bad xml response from cam". The second thing is - do you know something about UDP-multicast camera's activation? In my company, we try to mirror SADP behavior. The problem with activation via "ISAPI" is that your "activation client" has to be in 192.16.1.x subnet. There is no such an issue with SADP.

Comment: I've already found out how to search devices via UDP-multicast. But there is problem with activation. I've sniffed  frames during SADP activation process. There are "exchange frames" first - similar to "challenge", but I couldn't even decode keys from them. These keys look like base64 from "challenge", but are much shorter. Then - after exchange, client is sending encoded password. It looks like SADP-activation and ISAPI-activation are very similar, but something is wrong. :(

Comment: @BartekGładys, if you use js you can look how web gui of camera itself make activation. It uses ISAPI too, but written on js.
I haven't worked with SADP, sorry.

Comment: Great answer.   The result of step 3 appears to be 128 bytes.  Should this array be used as the AES key?

Comment: @Hong, no, there should be only 16 bytes for AES key. Look in the python script, function set_activation().

Comment: @qb60 Thank you for your prompt response.  I use Java.  The code equivalent to your: random_key_text = private_key.decrypt(random_key_bin)[-32:]  returned 128 bytes. Do you get only 16?

Comment: @Hong, oh, right. You need to use only last 32 bytes of those 128.
this line:

`random_key_text = private_key.decrypt(random_key_bin)[-32:]`

means:

`random_key_text_full = private_key.decrypt(random_key_bin)

random_key_text = random_key_text_full[-32:]` <- and this means you should take only last 32 symbols (and then convert them to 16-bytes array for AES key)

Comment: @qb60  Thanks a lot for clarifying this.  It makes a lot of sense now.  I will proceed as instructed and report back soon.  I know little about Python, so I read your code with a lot of guesses.

Comment: @qb60 It is working.  I am wondering if it is because I use cipher.unwrap(abResponse, "ALGORITHM_AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY)  instead of simply simple RSA  decryption.

Comment: @qb60 Could you tell me the approximate length of Result base64 string of step 6?

Answer (score 1):

Final script running in PhantomJS thanks to Artjom B pointing me at that program (note: Used a different password in the final script, and the model of camera always uses the IP address of 192.168.1.64 on this firmware, so hard-coding that makes sense)

Edit: The below apparently works on HIKVISION firmware 5.3.0 only.  I briefly played with a camera on HIKVISION firmware 5.3.4, and they had changed the javascript file names, as well as the button and field names.

```js
/**
 * Wait until the test condition is true or a timeout occurs. Useful for waiting
 * on a server response or for a ui change (fadeIn, etc.) to occur.
 *
 * @param testFx javascript condition that evaluates to a boolean,
 * it can be passed in as a string (e.g.: "1 == 1" or "$('#bar').is(':visible')" or
 * as a callback function.
 * @param onReady what to do when testFx condition is fulfilled,
 * it can be passed in as a string (e.g.: "1 == 1" or "$('#bar').is(':visible')" or
 * as a callback function.
 * @param timeOutMillis the max amount of time to wait. If not specified, 3 sec is used.
 */

"use strict";
function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 3000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
};


var page = require('webpage').create();

// Open camera and, onPageLoad, do...
page.open("http://192.168.1.64/doc/page/login.asp", function (status) {
    // Check for page load success
    if (status !== "success") {
        console.log("Unable to access network");
    } else {
        page.viewportSize = {
                width: 800,
                height: 600
        };
        // Wait for 'signin-dropdown' to be visible
        waitFor(function() {
            // Check in the page if a specific element is now visible
            return page.evaluate(function() {
                return $("#btnOK").is(":visible");
            });
        }, function() {
           console.log("The sign-in dialog should be visible now.");
                //page.includeJs("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js", function() {
                page.includeJs("http://192.168.1.64/doc/script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", function() {
                        page.evaluate(function() {
                                $('#newPassword').val("MyPassword1");
                                $('#newComfirmPassword').val("MyPassword1");
                                $('#btnOK').click();
                        });
                });
                window.setTimeout(
                        function() {
                                page.render("test.png");
                                phantom.exit();
                        },
                        5000);
                //phantom.exit();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I now have an answer to why not automate the web page: They change field names when they update the firmware.  Oh well.  It just means I'll need to rewrite the script every time they update the firmware.  How often will they do that?

Comment: ... and I now have an answer to "How often will they do that?" of "Every few months, with no warning, and they don't even put the new firmware on their website, they just start shipping the new cameras with it"

Answer (score 0):

Hikvision cameras uses a protocol for activation called SADP.

You can use SADP SDK to find cameras on the network and also to activate it.

Look at ftp://ftp.hikvisionusa.com/ for the SDKs. They have builds for Windows, linux, android and iOS.